# Opencart 2.3.0.2 - new custom theme not available in the admin panel

Tags: opencart

I create new custom theme by copy paste default theme of Opencart 2.3.0.2 and rename it but this theme is not display in admin panel->System->Settings and Your Store (Default)=> 'Edit'. Anybody can help me this regard.
Thank you anticipation .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got answer.

Extensions >> Themes (Select From Dropdown) >> Edit (Your Theme) >> Theme Directory (Select Your theme in dropdown and press Save).
Your theme will be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answered deleted. Here is a link (and instructions from it):

http://undefined.gr/site/2016/10/09/custom-opencart-2-3-0-2-theme/

1. Copy folder upload/catalog/view/theme/default ->
   upload/catalog/view/theme/mytheme
2. Copy file
   upload/admin/controller/extension/theme/theme_default.php ->
   upload/admin/controller/extension/theme/mytheme.php

   - Change class name in the file mytheme.php from ControllerExtensionThemeThemeDefault to ControllerExtensionThemeTFM
     (line 2).
   - In mytheme.php replace all “theme_default” text to “mytheme“.
3. Copy file upload/admin/view/template/extension/theme/theme_default.tpl to
   upload/admin/view/template/extension/theme/mytheme.tpl

   - In mytheme.tpl replace all “theme_default” text to “mytheme“.
4. Copy file upload/admin/language/en-gb/extension/theme/theme_default.php
   to upload/admin/language/en-gb/extension/theme/mytheme.php.

   - In mytheme.php change the theme title (line 3).
5. Rename file upload/catalog/view/theme/mytheme/image/default.png to mytheme.png.

Answer (score 1):

In the 2.3.x version is a bit more complicated. The following is a step by step.

1. Download the files.

   - admin/controller/theme/theme_default.php
   - admin/language/english/theme/theme_default.php
   - admin/view/template/theme/theme_default.tpl
   - catalog/view/theme/default/* //Download the entire folder
2. Rename files from the folder **admin/*** of *theme_default* to "theme_custom".
3. Rename the folder *catalog/view/theme/default* to *custom*
4. Open the file **admin/controller/theme/theme_default.php** and replace all words *default* to *custom*.
5. Create a folder called *upload* and move all the folders downloaded in step 1 into it.
6. Zip and rename it to **custom.ocmod.zip** and send through the OC installer.